# QGIS - plot points on a map proportionally to column values

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a .csv file like as follow:

```
latitude | longitude | norm_imp
-22.13   |  -43.18   |  0.017
-22.19   | -43.29    |  0.038
-22.33   |  -43.08   |  0.117
-22.19   | -43.29    |  0.2038
```

I plot the latitude and longitude points on a layer, but I need these points to be proportional to those in the norm_imp column. Is it possible to do this in QGIS? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the "data defined override" for the size, see pictures below:

[image]

then you can use your field directly or use the asistent to make a proper size function:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, work perfectly